# How to intercept incoming email and retrieve message body in thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

In my Thunderbird add-on I want to listen to new incoming emails and process the message body.

So I have written a `mailListener` and added it to an instance of `nsIMsgFolderNotificationService`.

The listener works fine and notifies when a mail comes. I get the `nsIMsgDBHdr` object which was fetched, but I cannot stream the message for the particular folder in the `msgAdded` function of my `mailListener`. it hangs, and I cannot even see the message body in the Thunderbird's message pane.

I think the `nsISyncStreamListener` used to stream the message from the folder waits for `OnDataAvailable` event which is not yet triggered inside the `mailListener`'s `msgAdded` function.

Any inputs on how to fetch message body when a new email comes? Below is the code for my `mailListener`

```
var newMailListener = {
        msgAdded: function(aMsgHdr) {
           if( !aMsgHdr.isRead ){
                let folder = aMsgHdr.folder;
                if(aMsgHdr.recipients == "myemail+special@gmail.com"){
                    let messenger = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/messenger;1"]
                    .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIMessenger);
                    let listener = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/sync-stream-listener;1"]
                        .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsISyncStreamListener);
                    let uri = aMsgHdr.folder.getUriForMsg(aMsgHdr);
                    messenger.messageServiceFromURI(uri).streamMessage(uri, listener, null, null, false, "");
                    let messageBody = aMsgHdr.folder.getMsgTextFromStream(listener.inputStream,
                           aMsgHdr.Charset,
                           65536,
                           32768,
                           false,
                           true,
                           { });
                    alert("the message body : " + messageBody);

                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. The solution I found (not easily) is to use `MsgHdrToMimeMessage` from [mimemsg.js](http://mxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/mailnews/db/gloda/modules/mimemsg.js) as Gloda is not available yet. This uses the callback function:

```
var newMailListener = {
  msgAdded: function(aMsgHdr) {
    if( !aMsgHdr.isRead ){
      MsgHdrToMimeMessage(aMsgHdr, null, function (aMsgHdr, aMimeMessage) {
       // do something with aMimeMessage:
       alert("the message body : " + aMimeMessage.coerceBodyToPlaintext());

       //alert(aMimeMessage.allUserAttachments.length);
       //alert(aMimeMessage.size);
      }, true);
    }
  }
};
```

And do not forget to include the necessary module:

```
Components.utils.import("resource:///modules/gloda/mimemsg.js");
```

More folow up reading can be found e. g. [here](http://blog.xulforum.org/index.php?post/2011/01/03/An-overview-of-Thunderbird-Conversations).